# Trouble with MODULE

Tags: syntax, warning-messages

I try to become familiar with the Modules and struggle :-(

I wrote a very very pretty example but got an exception:

```
Analyse [data_, name_] :=
 Module [{};
  Text[Row[{"data is:", data}]];
  Text[Row[{"name is:" , name}]];
  ]
```

call for:

```
Analyse [1, "Paul"]
```

Result:

> Module::argmu: Module called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> Module[{}; Text[
>  Row[{"data is:", 1}]]; Text[
>   Row[{"name is:", "Paul"}]];]
> ```

So what is missing. I dont see the 1(!) argument, I have two. 
But there must be an issue for

thx

Comment: You need to be a bit (perhaps a lot) more careful about your `;` and `,`.  Try replacing the first `;` in the `Module...` with a `,`, see what happens, then consult the documentation to consolidate your learning.

Comment: Thanks..i did. i have got the structure from an example..

now i have changed but i expected to get to lines printed but nothing happend ;-)

Comment: @MelanieGerster Which example? p.s. take a look at [Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/5478) and other problems mentioned in this topic.

Comment: i am sorry, i thought (and read) i have to every statement by a semicolon in a module in opposite to the "normal" notebook, where i need no semicolon

Comment: Correct, but you need to also know what `;` does.

Comment: removing the semicolons worked..strange...so i have had a bad example

Comment: It worked but now it is like `2 2`, it multiplies the content in `Module`, if you need to output a `Grid/Column` or something like that, just use it.

Comment: could you help me with a good documentation and NOT the standard of Wolfram, which i do NOT understand at all

Comment: Have a look at this [introduction to Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/). It should cover all the issues you have had very early on.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You will find it helpful to look at the *examples* on each documentation page.  You may want to go through this too: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/  It is very old but almost everything in there is still relevant and essential for understanding Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the issue, remember that everything in *Mathematica* is an expression:

```
head[ e1, e2, ... ]
```

The `;` is a shortcut for [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html):

```
CompoundExpression[ expr1, expr2] === (expr1; expr2)

(* True *)
```

You can see what is happening by using [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
Analyse [data_, name_] := Module [{};
  Text[Row[{"data is:", data}]];
  Text[Row[{"name is:" , name}]];
] // FullForm
```

Testing your function again reveals an error message and a full form display of the specific DownValue for `Analyse[]` (which I have commented and reformatted for clarity):

```
Analyse[ 1, "Paul" ]
```

> Module::argmu: Module called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected.

```
Module[
  (* argument 1 *) 
  CompoundExpression[
     List[],
     Text[Row[List["data is:",1]]],
     Text[Row[List["name is:","Paul"]]],
     Null
   ]

   (* slot for missing argmument 2 *)

]
```

So, your two arguments have been well taken, but the [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)is only having one argument, which is the `CompoundExpression`. Module does take two arguments:

```
Module[ {vars}, body ]
```

So simply drop the last semicolon (because you do not want `Null` being the last expression in a compound expression and thus have no output) and replace all other semicolons by `,` as shown by *e.doroskevic*.

Comment: @MelanieGerster By now it should be clear why you will need `;` for the `body` part of `Module`:  Module only takes two arguments thus a whole bunch of expressions need to be given as one `CompoundExpression`.

Comment: Since OP is not familiar with the proper usage of `Module` and seems to be using it without any local variables only as a grouping construct, perhaps worth mentioning as well that simply replacing `Module` with `CompoundExpression` for this application is probably the easiest fix.

Answer (score 1):

### Description

The issue you've experienced is due to semantics applied. Please see a working example below. Also, see reference provided.

### Example

```
Analyse[data_, name_] := Module[
  {},
  {Text[Row[{"data is:", data}]],Text[Row[{"name is:", name}]]}
]
```

If you want to wrap the above into a column structure, simply add `Column` to the `List` containing the `Row` data. Like below

```
...
Column @ {Text[Row[{"data is:", data}]],Text[Row[{"name is:", name}]]}
...
```

### Reference

[Module](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)